# excel VBA code not working

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a excel sheet with a VBA code as follows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 5 Then
        Dim iRet As Integer
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("AZ1").Value) Then
            iRet = MsgBox("You have already selectd a Size Template", _
                          vbOKOnly, "Select Size Template")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Split(Target, ",")
        Range("R14:AZ14").ClearContents
        Range("R14:AZ14").NumberFormat = "@"
        Range("R14", Cells(14, UBound(arr) + 18)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose( _
                                        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr))
        Range("AZ1").Value2 = Target
    End If
End Sub
```

I saved the excel file as .xlsm(macro enabled excel file) and opend in another.This code works really fine in my machine. BUt not in any other machine. I enabled the marco and allowed the Trust acess to the VBA ojbect model. CAn anybody figure out the issue here . Excel versions are also same in both mahcines
[image]

Comment: any errors? On this new machine try to open VBA/IDE Editor and run this in Immediate window: `Application.EnableEvents = true`.

Comment: `1` Hope you have enabled macros in the destination pc as well? If yes, see next step `2` In the immediate window type "Application.EnableEvents = True" and press Enter key `3` If it still doesn't work then manually check if the code is getting executed or not and then we will take it form there...

Comment: I add the following code and its solve the problem to me Thanks
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: @udaya726 - if Events are *disabled* then how does your `Activate` sub get called? `Trust Access to VBA project` is not required here: that's only relevant if you're using code to (eg) create or edit other code in a macro-enabled workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to elaborate a bit the comment of mine which was correct suggestion.

**First,** let me repeat that- you need to switch on events in this way

```
Application.EnableEvents = true
```

which you can be run once in Immediate Window in VBA/IDE Editor. Now we know that was it!

**Second,** if you decided to switch on events using any other subroutine (or event, which is however strange) please keep in mind that there could be some other subroutines, functions or add-ins which require events to be switched off. As long as you are not sure why events are not working you should keep them not working right after your macro doesn't need them any more. Therefore, my suggestion is to switch events off each time you will close your file. Therefore you could add this event to `ThisWorkbook module`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub
```

**Extra tip**. The best option would be to read events status at the beginning, keep this information until you close your file. You could do it in the following steps:

**A)** declare public variables in your file

```
Public boEventsStatus as Boolean
```

**B)** read status when opening file (you need to figure it out where put this line of code)

```
boEventsStatus = Application.EnableEvents
```

**C)** switch on events as described at the beginning

**D)** use this `BeforeClose` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = boEventsStatus
End Sub
```

Comment: If events are off then how do any of these event handlers get fired?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I don't say any event fire in such situation, do I? I mentioned either `immediate window` or I said "you need to figure it out where put this line of code" referring to uniqueness of each situation. However, D point will fire as a result of C point...

Comment: I guess I read your response too quickly, and following on from the OP's comment with code which "solved" their problem (and cannot have done as far as I can see...) Apologies - you do not say what I'd implied

Comment: I add the enable events in event Private Sub Workbook_Open().Seems like at that moment its not work