# Initializing ComboBox failing

Tags: vba, excel, user-controls

My sheet contains a combo box that is supposed to drop down, you choose a team and the sheet updates to that team.  Everything I've done so far works perfectly except that nothing I do initializes the combo box without going into VBA and manually triggering the initializing event.  I am not familiar with using these on regular sheets, and I didn't feel that creating a userform for one selection was prudent.

```
    Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim akw As Worksheet
    Dim akd As Worksheet
    Set akw = Worksheets("Agent KPI Per Week")
    Set akd = Worksheets("Agent KPI Per Day")
    On Error Resume Next
    With akw.OLEObjects("PWTeamSelect").Object
        .Clear
        .AddItem "01 XT"
        .AddItem "02 XT"
        .AddItem "03 XT"
        .AddItem "04 XT"
        .AddItem "05 XT"
        .AddItem "06 XT"
        .AddItem "07 XT"
        .AddItem "08 XT"
        .AddItem "09 XT"
        .AddItem "10 XT"
        .AddItem "11 XT"
        .AddItem "12 XT"
        .AddItem "13 XT"
        .AddItem "14 XT"
        .AddItem "15 XT"
        .AddItem "t01 XT"
        .AddItem "t02 XT"
        .AddItem "t03 XT"
        .AddItem "t04 XT"
    End With

    With akd.OLEObjects("PDTeamSelect").Object
        .Clear
        .AddItem "01 XT"
        .AddItem "02 XT"
        .AddItem "03 XT"
        .AddItem "04 XT"
        .AddItem "05 XT"
        .AddItem "06 XT"
        .AddItem "07 XT"
        .AddItem "08 XT"
        .AddItem "09 XT"
        .AddItem "10 XT"
        .AddItem "11 XT"
        .AddItem "12 XT"
        .AddItem "13 XT"
        .AddItem "14 XT"
        .AddItem "15 XT"
        .AddItem "t01 XT"
        .AddItem "t02 XT"
        .AddItem "t03 XT"
        .AddItem "t04 XT"
    End With
End Sub
```

This is my code for the Open_Workbook.

Comment: Are you looking for an "On Change" event when the user selects an item from the ComboBox?

Comment: No, I am looking to load this workbook and be able to click on the drop box.  Right now when it happens one of two things occur depending on how the book was saved.  1.  The value of the comboboxes is whatever I saved it as, or two, I manually initialize these and they are blank.  In either case, there are NO options for me to choose from when I reload the workbook, and I want there to be :/

Comment: Remove the `On Error` line what happens?

Comment: Nothing happens.  That's the issue lol.  Doesn't matter if 'On Error' is there or if it's public, private, literally nothing happens on load.  I can manually trigger the initialization from the code, but it won't do it on it's own.

Comment: Where do you have the Sub stored?

Comment: On the worksheet that it's calling from

Comment: In the `ThisWorkbook` module or in a separate module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222217/excel-vba-code-not-working

Comment: in the workbook it's calling from ThisWorkbook

Comment: It appears that you are using a form control, which are always really picky to deal with. If this is the case then I would suggesting using an activex control instead. They are much easier to manage. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I must apologize, as I mentioned in my first question, this was really the first time I was trying to do this.  What I didn't realize was that the code needs to be in the Excel Object: ThisWorbook (Module).  I was placing the code on the Object for the individual worksheets.  This is what was messing me up.

Once I copied the code over to that object, it worked just fine.  In all of the research that I did I did not see anyone mention ThisWorkbook, and I didn't put two and two together when I read Chrismas007's response when he specifically asked if it was in ThisWorkbook.

Thanks for the assistance...

G

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of combo box you can add to a worksheet: either Form Control (circled in red) or ActiveX (circled in green).

[image: Combo Box options called out]

Based on the behavior you describe, I think you have mismatched your code and your combo box.

With an ActiveX combo, the code you wrote should work (I copied it exactly as you wrote it and the combo boxes populated). Just create new combo boxes using the ActiveX option (circled in green), name them correctly, and I think your code will work.

If you want to keep the combo boxes you've created and modify the code, replace the first line with a `Shapes` reference as shown here and the population should work. Note that I have removed the `.Clear` statement, which would throw an error in this context:

```
With akw.Shapes("PWTeamSelect").ControlFormat
    .AddItem "01 XT"
    .AddItem "02 XT"
    .AddItem "03 XT"
    .AddItem "04 XT"
    .AddItem "05 XT"
    .AddItem "06 XT"
    .AddItem "07 XT"
    .AddItem "08 XT"
    .AddItem "09 XT"
    .AddItem "10 XT"
    .AddItem "11 XT"
    .AddItem "12 XT"
    .AddItem "13 XT"
    .AddItem "14 XT"
    .AddItem "15 XT"
    .AddItem "t01 XT"
    .AddItem "t02 XT"
    .AddItem "t03 XT"
    .AddItem "t04 XT"
End With
```

Comment: I deleted the CB just to make sure of that and created a new one.  Still having the same issue.  If I manually fire my Public Sub Trigger() or Public Sub Workbook_Open() the CB Populates.  -- And just to be certain, this code should go on the worksheet itself, yes?  Since it's an ActiveX component that is stored on that sheet?